# String to unsigned 16-bit integer

Tags: esp32, convert

I'm currently working on a project with a 4DSystems Display. Im talking to the Display over SoftwareSerial with an ESP32. As soon as I want to use a Unicode character it requires me to convert my whole String to a uint16_t. Can somebody help me I have no idea how I should go on with this?

```
  #include <genieArduino.h>
  void loop() {
    uint16_t tn[] = { 0x2126,0 }; // Ω
    genie.WriteStrU(0, tn);
  }
```

This works but how could I inset a variable into the uint16_t?

Comment: Please provide the code that you have, error messages that you got and links to the used parts and libraries.

Comment: Which Arduino is this for?

Comment: I haven't seen that display library before, but probably it would be easier to only write the actual unicode characters via the unicode function and the rest with the normal write functions. Or is there a specific reason why you want to put another (probably numeric) variable inside that unicode string? From the documentation of the library it is unclear what encoding actually is used there. Maybe it would also work to just write the normal ASCII data in your unicode string, just casted to uint16_t (leaving the high byte empty).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by chrisl in a comment, your best option is to to use the
regular `WriteStr()` method to print variables, and use `WriteStrU()` to
print Unicode string constants. For example:

```cpp
float R = 12.34;  // dummy resistance value.
genie.WriteStr(0, "R = ");
genie.WriteStr(0, R);
genie.WriteStrU(0, (uint16_t *) u" Ω");
```

should print:

```
R = 12.34 Ω
```

Note the use of the `u` string prefix to write UTF-16-encoded strings in
the source code.

---

**Edit**: You wrote

> the `WriteStr` always replaces the text inside a String object instead
> of adding on.

This makes things more complicated. The only option I see is to format
the whole message as UTF-16 beforehand, then send it with `WriteStrU()`.
Here is a class that does simple UTF-16 formatting. It inherits from the
`Print` class, meaning you can `print()` to it anything you could print
to `Serial`. In addition, it can print UTF-16 strings:

```cpp
template <size_t max_length>
class UTF16Writer : public Print {
public:
    // Convert ASCII to UTF-16.
    size_t write(uint8_t c) {
        if (length >= max_length)
            return 0;  // buffer full
        buffer[length++] = c;
        buffer[length] = 0;  // terminate string
        return 1;
    }
    // Record UTF-16 data.
    size_t print(const char16_t *s) {
        size_t chars_written = 0;
        while (*s && length < max_length) {
            buffer[length++] = *s++;
            chars_written++;
        }
        buffer[length] = 0;  // terminate string
        return chars_written;
    }
    using Print::print;
    uint16_t buffer[max_length + 1];
private:
    size_t length = 0;
};
```

The template parameter is the capacity of the buffer. Once you have
written the whole message as UTF-16 using this class, you can pass its
`buffer` member to `WriteStrU()`. For example:

```cpp
float R = 12.34;  // dummy resistance value.
UTF16Writer<16> writer;
writer.print("R = ");
writer.print(R);
writer.print(u" Ω");
genie.WriteStrU(0, writer.buffer);
```

**Note**: Do not forget the `u` prefix in the Unicode string, otherwise
the bytes of the string (UTF-8 in the source) would be interpreted as
latin1 by `UTF16Writer::print(const char*)`. A message such as `"martine écrit en UTF-8"` would then be displayed as “martine Ã©crit en UTF-8”.